# Javascript prompt command executes before the documents writes

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>The Ultimate Quiz Challenge</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>The Ultimate Quiz Challenge</h1>
  <script>
  document.write("<h3> " + "Welcome to the ultimate quizz challenge" +"</h3>");
  document.write("<p> "+"Hi I will ask you five questions and then rank you" + "</p>");
  var question1 ="<p>What is the capital of England</p>";
  var firstanswer ="London";
  var question2 = "<p>How many sides are there to a square</p>";
  var secondanswer = 4;
  var noofquestions = 2;
  var count = 1
  /*var temp = eval('question' +1); */
  /*document.write(temp);*/
  /* main loop asking questions */
  while (count <= 2) {
      var temp = eval('question' + count);
      document.write(temp);
      var answer = prompt("Please type your answer "); 
      count++;
  }
  </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the file into a browser such a chrome or safari it does not execute as  hoped.

In short the document.write commands do not come out onto the screen until the prompt window as asked for two inputs. I thought the first thing to be seen would be the Ultimate Quiz Challenge followed by the commands in the open script tag down to the bottom ?

Comment: The page probably won't render until that script finishes, and the rest of the document gets evaluated. Try putting the `prompt` and related code inside a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: You should try to learn using of arrays. It's nice

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [`onload`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event on your body, so your script executes once the html page is rendered. It should work with :

```
<body onload="displayText()">
```

`displayText()` being a function you define in your script :

```
var displayText = function () {
  while (count <= 2) {
    var temp = eval('question' + count);
    document.write(temp);
    var answer = prompt("Please type your answer "); 
    count++;
  }
};
```

or something similar.

Comment: Why do I need this won't the commands execute from the top down by default without the need to call the function which is just a name for a block of code.  which I thought would execute as it is encountered. I am finding that alert boxes and prompt for example seem to take precedence over other commands, which means they display first then when they are responded to go away and display the text, when the order is text first.

Comment: Yes, JS executes top-down, but function declarations do not immediately get executed; they only get executed when *called*.  You use the function and the event handler to ensure the code doesn't execute too early (before the DOM is rendered)

Comment: "alert boxes and prompt for example seem to take precedence over other commands"   That's incorrect.  Do you mean they they *block* execution?  There is nothing special about their order of precedence.